# Category Base doesn't work (permalinks)

Tags: php, wordpress

I set permalinks to `Custom Structure` with these settings: `/postCategory/%category%/%postname%/`.
Also I set up `Category Base` to `postCategory`. 
And this will not work. When I visit post page I am getting page not found.

This produces:

```
for posts: example.org/postCategory/%category%/%postname% // this will output page not found
for categories: example.org/postCategory/%category% // this works
```

This doesn't work only when I use the same word for `Category Base` and for prefix in post URL (in this case `postCategory`).

So this doesnt work:

```
Custom Structure: /postCategory/%category%/%postname%/
Category Base:  postCategory
```

and this will work:

```
Custom Structure: /postCategory/%category%/%postname%/
Category Base:  postCategories
```

So my questions is how I can get this work. To have the same word for `Category Base` and in permalinks for post.

These are my permalinks settings:

http://pokit.org/get/img/8a33b710bf98f9e3658edaaf8343cc3b.jpg

**EDIT:**

I found something similiar here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58471/including-category-base-in-a-post-permalink-results-in-404

But I don't really understand how to set this function "add_rewrite_rule" for my case:

I have this problem with my custom post type: "product" and custom taxonomy: "product_cat" and want to use "vaporizers" for category base and in permalinks for "product"

So this is my desired setting for permalinks:

http://pokit.org/get/img/bad3b8bea220768b60bb73d49657974a.jpg

And the result for category should be:

www.example.com/vaporizers/product_cat_name

For product:

www.example.com/vaporizers/product_cat_name/product_name

Comment: That's interesting. I have found similar oddities in WP where it refused to allow me to use certain words in the url structure, like "search" - Only way around it was to not use that word. Maybe postCategory is reserved somehow and their error system doesn't factor this in to tell you exactly why you can't use it... just a theory.

Comment: I don't think that postCategory is reserved somehow, it's now just about postCategory it is problem if you use the same word for Category Base and in post permalink. So it could be also

**Custom Structure: /somethingElse/%category%/%postname%/** and
**Category Base:  somethingElse**

It still will not work. So I think that it will get confused because there will be similiar URLS for two diferent things

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because the category base internal rewrite rule takes precedence in the permalink structure rules (i.e. category rewrites come before post rewrites). So example.org/postCategory/%category% is interpreted as example.org/index.php?category_name=postCategory/%category% and, obviously, WordPress can't find such category, returning 404 page.  It will never search for posts after it fails on the category.

The only work around is to give one more base to a category or post... just like in you "and this will work" example.  They have to be different, there's no other way.